# JQuery toggle() and auto refresh/rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

enclosed a snipped of my code.
i wish to implement the simplest mechanism of authentication.
there are two input fields, *user* and *password*.
when clicking the send button, the verify() function is invoked, which checks whether the *username* and *password* are both "*admin*", if it holds then it displays the *isCorrect* div, and the *isWrong* otherwise.

thanks!

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="header">
            Username: <input type="textbox" tabindex="1" id="username"/>
            Password: <input type="password" tabindex="2" id="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="3" id="send" onclick="verify()"/>
        </form>

        <div id="isCorrect">correct!</div>
        <div id="isWrong">wrong!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.css

```
#isCorrect { display: none; }
#isWrong { display: none; }
```

test.js

```
function verify() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
        $("#isCorrect").toggle();
    else
        $("#isWrong").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Where is your question ?

Comment: Please don't user this method for authentication, it is not secure at all, the username and password will be visible in the source code of the page!

Comment: the goal is achieved but cannot be noticed, since it seems that the page is somehow being refreshed to the previous state.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz, i know it is not the best practice. i am just trying to implement the simplest silly mechanism ever.

Comment: add `return false;` to the end of the verify method ... this will keep you on the current page

Comment: @ManseUK, not working. and by the way, why do you think it should fix the issue?

Comment: @MrIzik because the form will be submitted if you don't !

Comment: @ManseUk, thank. but it is not working. is there any way to achieve this simple goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly as @Dunhamzzz pointed out - this is **VERY** unsecure as your username and password is  visible within the browser ....

If you want to keep the user on the screen to view the message you need to `return false;` to the end of your verify() function :

```
function verify() {
    $("#isCorrect").hide();
    $("#isWrong").hide();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
        $("#isCorrect").show();
    else
        $("#isWrong").show();
    return false;
}
```

And then update your html :

`<input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="3" id="send" onclick="return verify()"/>`

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/ZyN93/

Comment: as i mentioned above, it still does not display the corresponding div.

Answer (score 1):

If the page if refreshing you can use jQuery to prevent the default event,witch in the case of the input should be a submit

```
jQuery("#send").click(function(e){

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    e.preventDefault();
    if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
        $("#isCorrect").toggle();
    else
        $("#isWrong").toggle();
});
```

If you still want to use verify, you could do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="3" id="send"/>

jQuery("#send").click(verify); //this binds the event

function verify(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this prevents the submit event
    //your code
}
```

Also, check Dunhamzzzs answer, he's right about the event, if you want to capture the submit instead of the click of the input

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried to paste it within the *verify()* method, and also as is on my javascript. same result as before.

Comment: If you want to use this code, you should remove the onclick property. With this code you are binding the click event with javascript (witch allows, for example, for multiple bindings). I'll edit the answer so you can still use verify

Answer (score 0):

Nicos answer has the logic right, but don't add a click event to the submit button, as it won't trigger when the user presses enter when on the form (plus you shouldn't do that anyway theses days), in jQuery you can add a submit handler to the whole form like so:

```
$('form.header').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This stops the form actually submitting

   var username = $("#username").val();
   var password = $("#password").val();

    if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
        $("#isCorrect").toggle();
    else
        $("#isWrong").toggle();
});
```